# GeoLite2 Country List Of Codes

Tags: geoip, maxmind

In the GeoLite2 Country database does anyone know if a list of the two character country/organisation codes can be found anywhere or what source its using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GeoLite2 and GeoIP2 databases use [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org) as a data source. See their [list of countries](http://www.geonames.org/countries/). Generally, the country codes follow ISO 3166-1.